# Batch rename using grep and sed from lynx output

Tags: rename, batch-processing, batch-rename

I want to batch rename some files using the lynx web browser output. I've tried using many variations but nothing that has actually worked.

There is a single line in each file that I want to use for the file name.

This is basically what I'm attempting:

```
for i in *.html ; do mv "$i" "$(lynx -dump -nolist -width=200 "$i" | grep --color=never '[0-9] - [0-9]' | head -n 1 | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' -e "s/'/'\\\\''/g; 1s/^/'/" | cut -c3-)" ; done
```

this is the result:

```
mv: cannot move 'old_file.html' to 'new_file.html': No such file or directory
```

any help is much appreciated!

Comment: It would be very helpful if you added an explanation of what you are trying to achieve, not just dump the non-working command.

Comment: The file names have no indication of the actual content and need to be renamed. I'm using `Lynx` to format each file then `grep` to retrieve the relevant info such as the date, forum name, etc. The end result will be the new file name. The script actually displays the target names properly, it's just when I attempt to rename the files it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's why it didn't work. The string contained `/`.
I added:
    `tr '/' '\\'` to change `\` to `/`.
Problem solved.

Here is the entire code:

```
for i in *.html ; do mv $i "$(lynx -dump -nolist -nonumbers -width=200 $i | grep --color=never '[0-9] - [0-9]' | head -n 1 | tr -s ' ' | tr '/' '\\' | cut -c3- | sed 's/$/.html/')" ; done
```

The files originally had names like:
    `357012.html` and were renamed: `01\01\01 - Linux forum, guide to bash scripting.html`, etc.